# how to bind and unbind click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to unbind previous click handler. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div  style="display:block; float:right; width:auto; color:#7c7c7c;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"  class="favourate_dextop" title="Add to Favorites" id="fav'.$data[$k]['id'].'"
        data-sess_id="'.$data[$k]['id'].'"
        data-name="'.$name_event.'"
        data-city="'.$event_city.'"
        data-country="'.$event_country.'" 
        data-event_url="'.$event_urls.'" >
    </a>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (localStorage.getItem('eventData') !== null) {
        $.each(eventData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('eventData')), function(id){
            $('#' + id).addClass('faved');
        });
    }

    $(".favourate_dextop").bind("click", function() {
        $(".favourate_dextop").unbind("click");
        console.log()
        favorite(this);
    });
});

function favorite(item){
    if (eventData[item.id] !== undefined) {
       delete eventData[item.id];
    } else{
        eventData[item.id] = $(item).data();
    }
    $(item).toggleClass('faved');
    localStorage.setItem('eventData', JSON.stringify(eventData));
}
```

The problems I'm having are:

- when i click on class on async loading divs then some times double click persisits.
- therefore i handle using bind and unbind function.

solution worked from me is i passes function name on href like :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="favorite(this)">

 but this wrong solution.
```

2 solution i tried

```
 $('.favourate_dextop').on("click", function(){ console.log("ajax call"); favorite(this); });
```

but this script fails sometimes .
 Any suggestions are most welcome.

i also tried with this solution  but noting works for me.

```
      function doStuff()
   {
   alert("before ajax");
   console.log("onload call"); 
    favorite(this); 

  }
 $('.favourate_dextop').on('click', doStuff);
 $('.favourate_dextop').off('click', doStuff);
```

2 . ajax file loading data dynamically i need to replicate same script .

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 if (localStorage.getItem('eventData') !== null) {
$.each(eventData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('eventData')),    

 function(id){
    $('#'+id).addClass('faved');
  });
}

function doStuf()
  {
  alert("ajax");
console.log("ajax call"); 
favorite(this); 

}
   $('.favourate_dextop').on('click', doStuf);
    $('.favourate_dextop').off('click', doStuf);
});
```

Comment: what `previous click handler` are you talking about? If code shown is being called multiple times use event delegation instead and only call code once

Comment: problem occurs in  async loading divs (ajax loading divs) ,

Comment: Then use event delegation

Comment: Try [jQuery .one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) This ensures the handler is executed at most once per element per event type

Comment: @Pugazh not if you call `one()` more than once  https://jsfiddle.net/1Lcfy643/1/ Yes it assures that ***each*** handler is only fired once, but can still add multiple handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write

```
$(document).on(event,selector, function)
```

instead of

```
$(selector).bind(event, function)
```

It will work with all dom elements, even those created dynamically after document is loaded.

Comment: $('.favourate_dextop').on("click", function(){ console.log("ajax call"); favorite(this); });

Comment: replace it by $(document).on('click','.favourate_dextop', function(){});

Comment: What do you mean about "it's not working" ? Is the favorite function not called? Do you still have persisting double clicks? Could you please publish your code ? Do you have errors in the console?

Comment: problem is that when dynamic div loading on click of favrtedesktopclass : using code $(document).on('click','.favourate_dextop', function(){ console.log("ajax call"); favorite(this);  }) then on console ajax call view two times.

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry but your jsfiddle doesn't work. What I need is an html sample after the binding or a sample  with a for loop which will create dynamically the div. regards

Comment: correct answer  $(document).delegate(".favourate_dextop","click",function(){
        alert("page 1"); favorite(this); 
    });

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just remove the class from the element. This way, other elements that are still clickable maintain their clickable state, but the current element you click on is no longer clickable.

In the following, you can have all elements with class `clickableClass` respond to click events, and once you remove the class from one of them, only one is no longer clickable, the rest will still maintain click functionality

```
<div id='firstButton' class='cssClass clickableClass'></div>
<div id='secondButton' class='cssClass clickableClass'></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.clickableClass').on('click', function() { code...});

 $('.clickableClass).on('someEvent', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('clickableClass');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    function handleClick() {
        $('.favourate_dextop').unbind('click', handleClick);
        alert('clicked');
    }
    $('.favourate_dextop').bind('click', handleClick);

});
```

Will handle a single click and unbind itself. Try it out on [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1vjzt5k/3/).

Comment: doesn't resolve the problem of OP adding the same handler multiple times  see:  https://jsfiddle.net/o1vjzt5k/4/

Comment: @charlietfl I must be missing something - I can't see where in the question that criteria is specified.

Comment: i need to  work with all dom elements, even those created dynamically after document is loaded.

Comment: @enigma because OP is loading the same script more than once and needs to either unbind `off()` before adding handlers or use event delegation just once

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me.

- use delegate function

  ```
     $(document).delegate(".favourate_dextop","click",function(){
       favorite(this); 
      });
  ```